# what do the column names stand for in table _v_session_brief in netezza?

Tags: sql, netezza

What is difference between session_id,pid and client_pid in _v_session_brief table in Netezza

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find this in the `nzsession` [documentation.](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSULQD_7.1.0/com.ibm.nz.adm.doc/r_sysadm_nzsession_cmd.html)

> ID: The ID of the session.
>
> PID: The process identification number of the command you are running.
>
> Client PID: The process identification number of the client system.

Comment: Does the Client PID stand for the socket ID? or is there any such column in some table to get that info? @jeremytwfortune

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know. It would make sense to populate this with something like a socket ID, but that isn't clear from their documentation. Since its roots are in Postgres, I would suggest taking a look at that documentation to figure out how it's populated.